# Tag de Audio não funciona no Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html5, wordpress, html5-audio

Boa tarde, galera!

Estou tendo um problema que não consigo ver uma solução no google ou com os teste que faço. Tenho um site onde existem algumas tag de áudio, elas funcionam normalmente nos navegadores como Mozilla, porém no Chrome ela aparece desabilitada, já testei o mesmo código limpo em uma página de teste e funcionou, porém nessa aplicação ela não roda.

Código abaixo:

```js
$(".ouvir").click(function() {
  var arq = $(this).parent().find('a.ouvir_oculto').attr('href');
  console.log('Here -> ' + arq);
  //$(this).parent().html('<audio controls type="audio/mpeg" src="'+arq+'" controlsList="nodownload" autoplay style="width:200px"></audio>');
  $(this).parent().html('<audio src="' + arq + '" controls="controls"></audio>');
  return false;
});

$('.meu_player').bind('contextmenu', function() {
  return false;
});
```

```html
<div style="clear:both; float:left; width: 470px">
  <div id="MediaPlayerOverview_<?= $contador; ?>" class="meu_player">
    <a href="<?php print get_sub_field('end_arquivo'); ?>" class="ouvir_oculto"></a>
    <a href="play" class="ouvir"><img src="<?php print bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/imagens/player.png" width="36" height="30"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

É uma aplicação **Wordpress**, onde ele busca o áudio cadastrado e implementa na tag ***audio*** dinamicamente. A principio ele faz o processo de forma certa, mas não consegue executar

Link: https://www.radioriodejaneiro.am.br/programa/ouvindo-voce/#gravacoes

Comment: Pra mim está funcionando, qual a tua versão do chrome?

Comment: Talvez [isto](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7391219?hl=pt-BR) possa te ajudar.

Comment: Agradeço antes de mais nada a ajuda de vocês.

A versão do meu Chrome @DenisRudneideSouza é Versão 80.0.3987.122. Eu tinha visto alguns fóruns falando que poderia ser navegador desatualizado, porém esse não é o meu caso, acredito eu, já que informa que é a ultima versão.

Comment: @Sam Até que faz sentido esse link que você mandou, pois o link do áudio está sem certificado, talvez seja alguma incompatibilidade. Como o link do player é de terceiros, vc acha que eu devo informar a eles sobre esse erro ou atualizar o certificado do meu site?